# Add attributes as String to DOM element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a list of attributes stored as a string variable. I want to add that variable to a `<div>`. I'm currently at a loss. What I have is as follows:

HTML:

`<div></div>`

JS:

`var attributes = 'data-id="123" data-type="content" data-order="1"'`

Desired Output:

`<div data-id="123" data-type="content" data-order="1"></div>`

Comment: Since your attributes are stored as a string, you need to first extract your data attributes and their values, loop through them, and then add them to your div, which you can do with jQuery's `.data()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var attributes = 'data-id="123" data-type="content" data-order="1"';
 attributes=attributes.split(" ");
i=0;
var d=document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
while (i<attributes.length){
d.setAttribute(attributes[i].split('=')[0],attributes[i].split('=')[1].replace(/\"/g,""));
i++;
}

alert(d.getAttribute("data-id"));
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
var div = document.getElementById('YOUR_ID');
var attributes = 'data-id="123" data-type="content" data-order="1"'
attributes.split(' ').forEach((attr) => {
   div.setAttribute(attr.split('=')[0], attr.split('=')[1]);
});
```

Comment: You would need to get rid of the double quotes in the data values though.

Comment: This breaks if there's a space inside an attribute value.

Comment: This also worked for my use, Thanks for contributing. The others were just a little more bulletproof.

Answer (score 2):

split the `attributes` string by spaces (**but not spaces inside the quotes**)

```js
var div = document.getElementById('test');
var attributes = 'data-id="123" data-type="content new" data-order="1"';
var arr = attributes.match(/[^\s="']+|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'/g);

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2)
  div.setAttribute(arr[i], arr[i + 1].replace(/"/g, ''));
```

```html
<div id="test">test</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split()` to split attributes on key-value and then use `forEach()` loop to add them to element.

```js
var attributes = 'data-id="123" data-type="content" data-order="1"'.replace(/"/g, '').split(/=| /)
attributes.forEach(function(e, i) {
  if(i % 2 == 0) $('div').attr(attributes[i], attributes[i + 1])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>DIv</div>
```

Comment: On every even number do something.

Comment: Right, but why only even numbers?

Comment: In fist case element from attributes with  `i` or 0  is key and `i + 1` or 1 is value, etc...